# Array is not fully initialized with data extracted from json array using PUSH & SHIFT

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make two arrays by extracting data from a json array using Push & Shift method. The json file is updated with new data periodically. But I am not able to populate the arrays with all & updated data. It is always last index[11] being populated. Rest 0-11 are always zero.

How to correct it.

Here is my code:

```
 <script>
     var Device_Data;
     var rssi, batt;

    function dspChrt(Device_Data) { 
    console.log(Device_Data);

        var rssiArray = [];
        var battArray = [];
        var N = 12;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            rssiArray.push(0);
            battArray.push(0); }

        //console.log(Device_Data[0].rssi);
        //console.log(Device_Data[1].battery_voltage_mv);
        rssi = Device_Data[0].rssi;
        batt = Device_Data[1].battery_voltage_mv;
        rssiArray.shift();
        rssiArray.push(rssi);
        battArray.shift();
        battArray.push(batt);

        console.log(rssiArray);
        console.log(battArray);

 </script>
```

**Output of console.log(Device_Data);**

```
288) […]
​[0…99]
​​0: {…}
​​​battery_voltage_mv: 131
​​​rssi: "-110"
​​​<prototype>: Object { … }
​​1: Object { rssi: "-134", battery_voltage_mv: 131 }
​​2: Object { rssi: "-125", battery_voltage_mv: 131 }
​​3: Object { rssi: "-132", battery_voltage_mv: 131 }
```

**Output of console.log(rssiArray);**

```
(12) […]
​0: 0
​1: 0
​2: 0
​3: 0
​4: 0
​5: 0
​6: 0
​7: 0
​8: 0
​9: 0
​10: 0
​11: "-110"
```

**Output of console.log(battArray);**

```
(12) […]
​0: 0
​1: 0
​2: 0
​3: 0
​4: 0
​5: 0
​6: 0
​7: 0
​8: 0
​9: 0
​10: 0
​11: 131
```

Comment: It's because you push 0 for these indexes (in `for` loop)

Comment: Yes, can  you tell how do I populate it fully ?

Comment: maybe you were thinking the functions were working in the other direction, look also `unshift` to insert at the beginning and `pop` to remove at the end

Comment: Yes, I need both pop & unshift OR shift, as one record come each update & one at the end need to be removed.

Comment: I could, but I don't fully get your intention... Are you going to map all `Device_Data` elements or only last 12?

Comment: @barbsan: As I can control how many records I send from device so putting all records coming from device will be more flexible I guess. Yes, all records coming from Device_Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code those:

filling the arrays rssiArray and battArray with 12 zeros.

Then you are removing the first element with .shift().

Now you have 11 zeros in your arrays.

Then you are adding one element to each array.

So you will have two arrays with the first 11 elements as zeros, then you get one element on position 11 which comes from the Device_Data object.

if you want to add elements to the first position in your arrays then you can use:

```
rssiArray.unshift(rssi);
battArray.unshift(batt);
```

The dynamic values will be added as the first elements to the arrays.

But i guess you want to copy the whole structure from Device_Data to your arrays?
Then you can do something like this:

```
 <script>
    function dspChrt(Device_Data) { 
        console.log(Device_Data);

        var rssiArray = [];
        var battArray = [];
        for(var i=0; i<Device_Data.length; i++) {
            rssiArray.push(Device_Data[i].rssi);
            battArray.push(Device_Data[i].battery_voltage_mv);
        }

        console.log(rssiArray);
        console.log(battArray);
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Yes, copy whole structure at first, & then with each update/dynamic data only last one index is to be update as one new record come with each update.

Comment: If you want to override the last element in one of your elements you can first pop then push, or do like this rssiArray[rssiArray.length - 1 ] = Device_Data[Device_Data.length - 1].rssi

If you want to copy the last element from Device_Data to your array.